# What does the "greater than" symbol in the expression: (1-X).*(X>1) mean?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB: What does the "greater than" symbol in the expression: (1-X).*(X>1) mean or do?

X is a column vector and theoretically each element of X lies in the range 0 to 1 inclusive. Numerically due to finite precision, an element might be slightly in excess of 1.0, so this may be a sort of condition or constraint.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context you describe, it is essentially "selecting" elements greater than 1 and subtracting them from 1; all other elements in the result (those in positions where `X <= 1`) will be 0 because they have been multiplied by the zero from the result of `X > 1`. Here is an example:

```
>> X = [0 0.5 1 1.5 2];
>> X > 1

ans =

 0     0     0     1     1

>> (1 - X)

ans =

1.0000    0.5000         0   -0.5000   -1.0000

>> (1 - X) .* (X > 1)

ans =

     0         0         0   -0.5000   -1.0000
```

In the last result, the three zeros in the first result have been multiplied (elementwise) with the first three values in the middle result, and the two ones have been multiplied by the last two values in the middle result. In this way, it has effectively selected the results of (1 - X) in the positions where X > 1 to begin with.

Obviously, if there are never any values of X greater than 1, then the result will always be all zeros.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(X > 1)` returns `true` (logical '1') for every element that is greater than 1, and `false` (logical '0') otherwise. Therefore, `X > 1` produces a boolean vector (of the same size as `X`) containing '1's where the corresponding elements in `X` are greater than 1. I strongly recommend that you get more familiar with [MATLAB operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html).

As for the rest of the expression:

`(1 - X)` simply returns an vector of the same dimensions as `X`, where each element is the result of subtracting the corresponding element in `X` from 1.

`.*` is an element-wise multiplication, so the final result is a vector (of the same dimensions as `X`), where the i-th element equals (1 - X<sub>i</sub>) if X<sub>i</sub>>1, and 0 otherwise.

#### Example

```
 >> X = [-1 4 0 2 -3];
 >> X > 1

 ans =
      0     1     0     1     0

 >> 1 - X

 ans =
      2    -3     1    -1     4

 >> (1 - X) .* (X > 1)

 ans =
      0    -3     0    -1     0
```